# Shell theme disabled gnome tweak tool

Tags: themes

Trying to install  tron legacy theme

But i am really stuck

the Shell theme is disabled its faded out:)

http://half-left.deviantart.com/art/GNOME-Shell-Tron-Legacy-208220836

trying to install gnome-shell via ubuntu software center but its says dependency problem

[code]gnome-shell: Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs-24-0 maar het is een virtueel pakket
             Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) maar 
1:4.0-0ubuntu11+kxstudio1 zal worden geïnstalleerd
             Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) maar 1:4.0-0ubuntu11+kxstudio1 zal worden geïnstalleerd
             Depends: libxi6 (>= 2:1.2.99.4) maar 2:1.7.1.901-1ubuntu1 zal worden 
geïnstalleerd
             Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1) maar
 3.12.1-0ubuntu1~trusty1 zal worden geïnstalleerd[code]